# Add content to element with CSS except when it's an image

Tags: css

I'm using a WordPress plugin that adds affiliate links. It has the class name 'thirstylink'.

Since I want affiliate links to be highlighted, I've added the following CSS to add an asterisk after each affiliate link:

```
.thirstylink:after {
    content: "*";
}
```

This styles links like this nicely with an asterisk at the end:

```
<a href="#test" class="thirstylink">this is an affiliate link</a>
```

However, I don't want linked images to be styled like this. For example...

```
<a href="#test" class="thirstylink"><img src="#imageofproduct"></a>
```

Is there a way I can add an asterisk to linked text with the class 'thirstylink' but not to a linked image? Can this be done with CSS or will I have to resort to Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not possible using current CSS.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe - that was what I feared. But I wondered if there was a clever hack!

Comment: The character is quite small... You could conceal it with a white `box shadow` on the image, but obviously this depends on the rest of your content.

Comment: @sol yeah, that might work, or other stuff like a negative margin-right for the image (that would pull the pseudo content “under” it, in combination with z-index) ... as long as the images are “solid”, and have no transparent parts.

Comment: Great ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible in CSS Now. but you can use jquery.

**Solution 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thirstylink:not(:has(img))").addClass('thirstylink-without-img');
});
```

and CSS

```
.thirstylink-without-img:after {
    content: "*";
}
```

**Solution 2:**

**This solution for future. it's not working now. but you can use this in future**

```
.thirstylink:not(:has(> img)):after {
  content: "*";
}
```

Here we use CSS [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo selector

Comment: Thanks so much, @patelarpan, that is perfect! I've added the Javascript for now. Do you know if and when the new CSS solution will be implemented?

Comment: welcome @iagdotme. sorry but I don't know when it's implemented.